# Subsampling - Choice of Subsample Size?

Tags: subsampling

I have a question with regard to Subsampling.

- Subsampling: take samples without replacement of size b from the original sample of size n with b < n
- Bootstrapping: take samples with replacement of size m from the original sample of size n with m = n

How do I choose b?

Comment: It depends, why do you want to subsample?

Comment: What does bootstrap have to do with the question?

Comment: I want to estimate confidence intervals

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to estimate. Usually, $b(n)$ should be chosen such that $b(n)\to \infty$ and $b(n)/n \to 0$ for $n\to \infty$ if you want the bootstrapping to work for estimating extreme order statistics (such as the maximum). What estimator are you trying to get confidence intervals of?